# Is there an App object in Blazor that I can modify?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In WPF there is a default object that is created called `App` which derives from `ApplicationBase`.  Developer can add properties etc. as desired.

Is there a similar concept in Blazor, and if so, how can I add a property to the `App` object?

Desired objective is to add a string property so I can do something like this:

```
App.StatusBarMessage = "Hello";
```

Thanks to answers below here is the final solution.   `MessageService` is a whopping two lines that's why I just wanted to add it to App.

MessageType and MessageService:

```
public enum MessageType
{ 
    None,
    Info,
    Warning,
    Error,
    Loading,
    LoadingComplete
}

public class MessageService
{
    public async Task ShowMessage(string message, MessageType messageType) => await Notify?.Invoke(message, messageType);

    public event Func<string, MessageType, Task> Notify;
}
```

Service registration in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MessageService>();
```

`MessageBox.razor` listens for events on `MessageService` and displays them:

```
@if (MessageType == MessageType.Loading)
{
    <img src="please_wait.gif" style="height:50px;width:50px" /> <h3>Loading....</h3>
}
else if (MessageType == MessageType.Info)
{
    <i class="bi bi-info-circle"></i> @Message
}
else if (MessageType == MessageType.Warning)
{
    <i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i>@Message
}
else if (MessageType == MessageType.Error)
{
    <i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i>@Message
}



@inject MessageService MessageService
@code {
    private MessageType MessageType;
    private string Message;
    private int LoadingCount;


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        MessageService.Notify += OnMessageReceived;
    }


    private async Task OnMessageReceived(string message, MessageType messageType)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            if (messageType == MessageType.Loading)
                LoadingCount++;
            else if (messageType == MessageType.LoadingComplete)
            {
                LoadingCount = Math.Max(0, --LoadingCount);
                messageType = LoadingCount == 0 ? MessageType.None : MessageType.Loading;
            }

            Message = message;
            MessageType = messageType;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }



    public void Dispose() => MessageService.Notify -= OnMessageReceived;
}
```

In some other control, inject `MessageService` and call `ShowMessage`:

```
@code{
    [Inject] private MessageService MessageService { get; set; }
    
    //...

    public async Task ErrorHandler(string msg)
    {
        await MessageService.ShowMessage(msg, MessageType.Error);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean config values ? You can define your own settings in appsettings.json https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: No, not config values.  I'm looking for a static object that exists that contains some .net properties that define the app.

Comment: What actual "properties" do you want to change?  What problem are you trying to solve?  I suspect this is a bit of an XY question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe what you need is a Singleton Service.

Define a class

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blazor.Starter.Services
{
    public class BaseService
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Add it to services in startup/Program as a singleton

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<BaseService>();
        }
```

Display/Consume/set it it in any component/page

```cs
<h3>@MyBase.Message</h3>

@code {

    [Inject] private BaseService MyBase { get; set; }

    void ConsumerMethod()
    {
        var x = MyBase.Message;
    }

    void SetterMethod()
    {
        MyBase.Message = "Bonjour";
    }
}
```

If you want to change it in one place and have it update somewhere else, you'll need to implement a notification service - [see here in MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state)